# MERGE INTO statement in MySQL and PostreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, hsqldb

I'm using HSQLDB and have a statement wich merges data to a table:

```sql
MERGE INTO USERS USING (VALUES(null,?,?))" +
"AS VALS(A,B,C) ON USERS.NAME = VALS.B 
 AND USER.EMAIL = VALS.C " +
"WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET USERS.NAME = VALS.B, 
 USERS.EMAIL = VALS.C " +
"WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES VALS.A, VALS.B, VALS.C
```

This statement updates a row if a user exists and creates a new one if not.

It looks like `MERGE INTO` is not supported by MySQL and PostgreSQL.

How to perform the same statement without using `MERGE INTO` in MySQL and PostgreSQL? I'd like to have the only one statement and with excellent perfomance.

Comment: MySQL has a different syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: In postgres 9.5+ use `on conflict` clause in insert statement https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Answer (score 0):

If your necessities are linked to some issues like MERGE for MySQL you can try to use this syntax:

```
UPDATE a
INNER JOIN b
  ON a.feild1= b.feild1
SET a.feild2= b.feild2
WHERE a.feild3 = 0;
```

It works for MySQL 5+ and I think it will work for MySQL 4+ as well.

[The source link of the solution](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/02/21/flexible-insert-and-update-in-mysql/)